# Failed to refresh a div when submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refresh a div when submiting a form, but I'm having a 404 error

> jquery.min.js:2 POST Https://xxxx.com.ar/Home/@Url.Action(%22Pagination2%22,%22Home%22) 404 (Not Found)

This is my form:

```
<form action="~/Home/Pagination" method="post" id="ajax_submit_siguiente">
         <button class="siguiente-imagen @ViewData["btnSiguiente"]" id="btnSiguientePaginacion" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
                                    Siguiente
          </button>
</form>
```

And this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ajax_submit_siguiente").submit(function (e) {

        // prevent regular form submit
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {
            'paginacion': 'siguiente',
            'entrega': $("#btnSiguientePaginacion").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Pagination","Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);

                // refresh
                $(" #container-galeria-imagenes").load(window.location.href + " #container-galeria-imagenes ");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

And this is my JsonResult...

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Pagination(string paginacion, string entrega)
{
  List<PedidoViewModel> list;

  // Working code....

  return Json(list);
}
```

I'm very new with ajax, I read the documentation and was like this how to refresh a div after sending a submit...

Answer (score 0):

since its a form submit rather than creating the object serialize the form and pass it to the server. also just to double confirm check the conversion of '@Url.Action("Pagination","Home")'is correct using the browser debugger tool and also make sure the routing is implemented correctly in Server side

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting normally
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/my/url',
      data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        $('#myDiv').html(response); // update the content of the div with the response
      }
    });
  });
});
```